# not able to load .pkl file

Tags: python, pickle

I have a dataset stored into .pkl file, I am trying to read the file, and using the bellow code.

```
with open('file.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

this is the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

while trying with

```
with open(wesad_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

this is the error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

i never dealt with .pkl file, so any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you use 'wb' or 'w' mode when writing the file?  The latter might have corrupted it.

Comment: I am trying to read the file, not write.. I downloaded an online dataset

Comment: If you could share the link of the pkl dataset, we could probably help more

Comment: i got one way around using  pd.read_pickle(filename) .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution:

```
    data = pd.read_pickle(filename)
```